# Solving an equation entered by the user via the Input function

Tags: equation-solving, wolfram-cloud, input

I am new to *Mathematica*. I am trying to create a program that takes in an equation from user input and then gives the answer. I started with a manipulate function as I created a similar program for graphs, but it didn't allow the range of equations I wanted it to, so I found the `Input` function. Here is my code:

```
Solve[Input["Give an equation to be solved, with x as the variable. There can only be one undefined variable. Put in two equals signs instead of one."], x]
```

When I evaluated the cell, it gave me a screen showing a my prompt and a box saying `Hold[Null]`. I tried replacing the entire phrase with my equation and replacing `Null` with my equation; both times it didn't show anything on the prompt box and when I exited the mini screen with the prompt it gave this error as output:

> Solve::naqs :$Failed  is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities

I'm not really sure what I did wrong after looking at the documentation. It could be something to do with how I'm inputting my response. Here's a screenshot of what I inputted:

[image: screenshot of input into program]

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Is there a problem with the input dialog box using *Mathematica* Online?

Comment: Try adding Evaluate[] before input

Comment: I added Evaluate[] and it didn't work. I am using Mathematica Online, so I don't know if that has anything to do with it. I also realized that there is a loading symbol at the bottom of my input screen; could the problem have anything to do with that?

Comment: I tried it in Woflram Cloud (free account), and no matter what I do, `Input[]` always returned `$Failed`.  Something is wrong with it.  Bug?

Comment: Works on the desktop version but not online.

Comment: @Young, did it work with `Evaluate[]` for you (I guess I should also ask, are you using Online or Desktop)?

Comment: There is no need for `Evaluate` because `Solve` has no `Hold*` attributes.  It's a problem specific to the online version.

Comment: So this is definitely a bug?

Comment: @Szabolcs do you see OK'/Cancel buttons at all? I don't :/