# Giving new input while program is running

Tags: interactive

This is a substantial edit of the initial question. Thanks to  MikeLimaOscar I can narrow my problem to the use of Input. I want Mathematica to ask me for a value that I will give if I find a complex number. I keep getting Null when I use it. I give a basic example:

```
    Module[{n, , x, i},
     Clear[n, x, i];
     n = Sqrt[{4., -1., 9.}];
     For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
      If[Element[n[[i]], Reals] == True,
       x[i] = n[[i]]*2,
       x[i] = Input["Introduce a value"]
       ]
      ];
     Table[x[i], {i, 1, 3}]]
    {4., Null, 6.}
```

Why doesn't it take into consideration the number I give?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without even a hint of the structure of your code this is difficult to answer but using `Input` (and `While`) is certainly a possibility.  For example, wrap your analysis function in something like: `While[Im[Chop[result = yourAnalysis[a, t, initialGuess]]] != 0, If[(initialGuess = Input["Enter new initial guess"]) == $Canceled, Abort[]]]`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am going to substantially edit my question because I realize I have a basic problem with the use of Input

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue.  When I input 12.1, the output is `{4., 12.1, 6.}`.  Perhaps try again with a fresh kernel?

Comment: Everytime I use Input I get Null result. I am even unable to reproduce the basic Input[]^2 that appear in the help documentation. Is there any setting in Mathematica that influences this?

Comment: Are you using Mathematica online?  If so [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118840/5414) is related.  Otherwise, I think you may have set the dreaded option `RequireReinstall` to `True`!

Comment: No, is not the online version. I still do not know what it was, but I reinstalled it and it works now. Many thanks.